# JFrame continuing to receive key strokes even after seeming to lose focus

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I have a Java app that I'll call *App*.  App will occasionally display a JFrame that we'll call *myFrame*.  App will also display a JTextArea that is contained in either a JDialog or a JFrame (I'm not sure which, but I can find out if that's necessary to answer this question).  Let's call this JTextArea "myTextArea".

Now, the following sequence of events happens:

1. We display myFrame.  It has the focus and you can give it input.
2. We call myFrame.setVisible(false)
3. We display myTextArea.
4. We call myTextArea.requestFocus().
5. myTextArea has the focus (the cursor is blinking with in it), but all the keystrokes that are input are sent to myFrame!

Note that myTextArea is not contained in myFrame.

What is going on here?  Has anyone heard of a non-visible JFrame receiving keystrokes?  Not only receiving keystrokes but stealing them from some other component that has the focus?

Comment: Never seen is happen. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I would *love* to post my SSCCE for this.  It's a huge application, though, and that may take some time.

Comment: If you don't get a proper solution soon, the time it takes to whittle your app down to an SSCCE may be time well spent. I predict that if you do this, you'll find the problem and solution yourself and won't even need our help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what’s basically causing the problem.  `MyFrame` has a class `MyKeyEventHandler` that implements `KeyEventDispatcher`.  The method `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)` is always returning false even for key strokes that are intended for `myTextArea`.  Therefore the key strokes do not reach `myTextArea`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about toggling the visibility. The JFrame is initialized first and still has focus. You are only making it invisible, not taking away the focus from it.

Moreover, your JTextBox needs to have a parent container. Possibly

> myFrame.add(myTextArea);

should work. To shift the focus to the JTextArea, use :

> myTextArea.requestFocus();

Comment: Sorry about the TextBox, that was TextArea.

Comment: Calling myTextArea.requestFocus() isn't fixing the problem (although maybe it's a necessary part of the fix).

Comment: When you make a frame invisible, the OS determines which other window on the desktop gets focus. I doubt using "requestFocus" will solve the problem, but even if it is a focus issue that is the wrong method to use. Read the requestFocus method API description for the proper method to use.